# Consuming Forecast.io Radar Data in an API or ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-server, rest, arcgis-rest-api

I want to consume [forecast.io's](http://forecast.io/#/f/45.5235,-122.6762) radar data as an ArcGIS Server REST or JSON to use in an API or ESRI's ArcMap GIS Software.  MapBox is doing it [here.](https://www.mapbox.com/labs/forecast/temperature/loop/) I don't think forecast.io is currently making the radar data service available as REST or JSON, it looks like they are using TileMill to serve out 16-bit grayscale GeoTIFF images of the radar data and applying some MapBox magic.  I want to do the same as a service for ArcGIS Server 10.2. I have looked into [Cutting Tiles for ArcGIS Server Using TileMill](http://blog.geomusings.com/2012/10/03/cutting-tiles-for-arcgis-server-using-tilemill/) but have not tested.
It's rumored that ESRI will build functionality into server to be able to consume MBtiles and that may be a potential solution, but for now I am looking for a workaround.
[Forecast for Developers](https://developer.forecast.io/docs/v2)

Comment: What is the question? "Help me" is too broad to be answered. Just edit your question to include a specific, answerable question. What have you done already? What happened? What did you expect to happen instead?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comment above that your question is too broad. It looks like you want to integrate this data with ArcMap. Since there doesn't seem to be a ready-to-go Esri-friendly version of this API, you'll probably need to look at building a plug-in data source.

The entry point for the Esri docs is here: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/#/Creating_a_plug_in_data_source/0001000004pz000000/